# How many different $7$-digit numbers can be formed from $0,1,2,2,3,3,3$ assuming no number can start with $0$? How many numbers will end with $0$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I got this question and wanted to confirm my solution.

> How many different $7$-digit numbers can be formed from $0,1,2,2,3,3,3$ assuming no number can start with $0$?  How many numbers will end with $0$?

For the first part, I got $360$, and for part 2, I got $60$.

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: would you like to show us your working?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you did it correctly when we don't know how you did it. We can answer whether you got the right results, but if you got those by rolling dice, that's not really worth anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those answers are correct. The answer for $1$) is

$$
\frac{7!-6!}{3!\cdot2!}=360\;,
$$

and the answer for $2$) is

$$
\frac{6!}{3!\cdot2!}=60\;.
$$